# Zooming a UIScrollView containing a ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to zoom and before it was working with a image in the scrollview. Now I'm trying to replace that image with a ViewController and zoom in on the object in that ViewController. It is not working.

viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.boardView = [[BoardViewController alloc] init];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.boardView.view];

[self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, 320))];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
```

viewForZoomingInScrollView:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return [self.scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

doubleTapped method: (it is calling this when I put a log in it, it's just not zooming.

```
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.boardView.view];

CGFloat newZoomScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale * 3.0f;
if (self.scrollView.zoomScale > self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale){
newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale);
}
else {
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale);
}

CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;

CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

[self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
```

I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: check what you are sending in `viewForZoomingInScrollView`

Comment: @CrazyCreator what should it be? I just added that, before I was using: return self.boardView.view; wasnt working either